# Duct acoustic modes

Tags: acoustics

I have [read](http://dx.doi.org/10.2514/6.2016-4792) that for a duct, the acoustic frequency is given by $$\omega = k_{lmn}=\sqrt{k_l^2+k_{mn}^2}$$ where $k_l$ and $k_{mn}$ are longitudinal and transverse wave number respectively.

Also, $k_{mn}$ can be obtained via $J_m'(k_{mn})=0$.($J_m$-Bessel function of m-th order)

Can anyone explain how is this derived or where does this come from?

Answer (score 2):

It consists in solving the wave equation(or Hemholtz equation) which involves the wave vector k. The boundary conditions introduced at the duct boundaries impose the quantization of the wave vector components.

The most simple picture of that is a basic 1D acoustic cavity of length L where the wavelength of the wave that can be sustained must be :

\begin{equation}
 m\lambda=2L ~~,~~ m\in\mathbb R
\end{equation}

where $k_m=2\pi/\lambda=m\pi/L$ . Technically $\omega$ should be related to the wave vector through the speed of the wave c $\omega = k_mc$.

In the case of a duct,it is slightly more complicated but essentially the same. Since the problem is 3D, the wave vector is quantized in 3 directions hence the presence of 3 indices.

Since the solutions of the wave equation in cylindrical coordinates are made of Bessel functions, the boundary conditions imposing the quantization of the wave vectors involves the zeros of the Bessel functions.